# How to present a view controller before main one is loaded?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I have a view controller but in the `viewDidLoad()` method I call another method named `authenticateUserAndConfigureView()` in which when the current user is nil it presents another view controller. However, it presents with it with a little delay - it firstly loads the main view controller and then the second one from the `authenticateUserAndConfigureView()` method.
Why is that?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    authenticateUserAndConfigureView()
    
    setUpElements()
}

func setUpElements() {
    
    // Style the elements
    Utilities.styleFilledButton(signUpButton)
    Utilities.styleHollowButton(loginButton)
    
    
}

func authenticateUserAndConfigureView() {

    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {

        print("No user signed in..")

    } else {

        print("User is already signed in.")
        
            
        let navController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeNVC")
        
        navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        
        self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't use login screens, but I can say there are *several* questions over the last few years here - along with (I assume) many tutorials out there. Good job showing what you've tried. Have you done a search? A quick one here on SO for "[swift] login view" returned 2575 hits.

Comment: Yes I tried searching for that. Maybe I am a bad searcher. However I somehow managed to fix that by just changing "animated" to false in `self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)`. But I get two warnings in console - Presenting view controller from detached view controller is discouraged, and Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: and so on. Should I worry about them? I have read that the unbalanced calls is because of 2 transitions happening at the same time but no answers to any of these errors. And if yes, they are in Swift 3.

Comment: Probably, at least a bit. Warnings do mean something - even if things work. I've had both of these warnings, and at the very least understand what they are trying to tell you. in order... (1) A detached VC means just that. From the sound of things, your root VC - declared in AppDelegate or anymore SceneDelegate - is probably presenting your login VC. BUT, it's not in the view hierarchy. (2) Unbalanced calls in my experience means you are trying to work with a navigation controller and the VC stack isn't necessarily correct. To me, #2 is the more important issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert this line inside `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated:Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   authenticateUserAndConfigureView()
}
```

**OR** make this check before presenting the MainVC and according to it present the suitable vc

Comment: I tried inserting this line but now it shows error `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: 0x7f877c04bc00>.`